# International Targeting & dinamic language page

Tags: google-search-console, hreflang, international

I have 3 types of pages on my site:

```
example.com/ru/about
example.com/en/about
example.com/about
```

pages with `ru` are in Russian, pages with `en` are in English, but page with none of those can be both in Ru and En, depending on `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`.

Now, Google says me that I have `no return tags` from `/ru/` to `/`, because `hreflang`s from `/ru/` leads to `/en/`.

What shoud I do in this situation? I suppose completely remove all hreflangs from `/` version?

Thanks a lot!

### Example

Let's pretend visitor is from Russia. Then a `/` page will be in Russian for him and will contain hreflang to `/en/`. But hreflang into `/en/` leads to `/ru/` version instead of `/`, as Google wants.

http://example.com/ - RU

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en/">
```

http://example.com/ru/ - RU

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en/">
```

http://example.com/en/ - EN

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/ru/">
```

P.S. There is a [live example](http://saranaisoft.com), please don't consider it as an advert.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of the hreflang links you implemented for your URLs for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What shoud I do in this situation? I suppose completely remove all hreflangs from / version?

This will eleminate the errors but is not the best choice for dealing whith your multi-language website.

Your Website actually has two languages available: EN and RU.

You decided to make use of language directories which is good. Actually there is no need of serving the same content outside of the language directories, as a user can only choose between RU or EN.

1. **Decide which language is the standard language you serve**

As already stated you have two versions of your page. I guess it would be okay to show the english version to everyone who does not apply to Russian language.

2. **Implement 302 redirection based on ACCEPT_LANGUAGE**

Leverage ACCEPT_LANGUAGE for 302 redirecting Russian language users to the /ru/ -directory URLs. 
Google will undestand you're redirecting users based on their ACCEPT_LANGUAGE settings.

3. **avoid serving other than Language-Directory URLs**

Make sure you do not serve URLs outside your language directories. Your homepage will be www.example.com/en/ an redirection will be applied as stated in step 2.

4. **Implement hreflang**

Implementing hreflang following this scheme:

for http://example.com/en/

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="http://example.com/ru/">
```

for http://example.com/ru/

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="http://example.com/ru/">
```

See: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077

---

Generally you can serve different language content on the same URL without using the language directories as Google is able to understand ACCEPT_LANGUAGE variations.
See: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055?hl=en